# Unable to disable the Add-in in Outlook 2010

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2010

I am developing a vsto COM Add-in with form region for Outlook. It works fine. However, I am facing problems disabling the Add-in in Outlook 2010.

From the File Menu > Options > Add-ins > COM Addins (dropdown) , I am unchecking my Add-in. But when I restart Outlook, the add-in is enabled again. If I check in the COM Addins list, its again enabled. Even the registry entries indicate that the Add-in is enabled again. Does anyone know what might have caused this? Can enabling and disabling be handled in my code, or will it be taken care by Outlook itself.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, its is a bug in Office 2010 Professional. To disable the add-in, you need to run Outlook as an admin, and then disable the add-in.

Answer (score 1):

If the addin is installed in both HKCU and HKLM, make sure you disable it in the HKLM registry hive.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko but disabling in HKLM will disable for all the users...which is not required for the author...it seems the value in HKLM is getting copied to HKCU and this is only reproducible in Outlook 2010 professional

Answer (score 1):

Typically when any changes made in the host application run under regular user privileges are written to the HKCU hive. For example, if the add-in is registed in the HKLM hive any changes in the UI are written to the HKCU hive due to the fact that the host application was not launched with admin privileges (which is required for writing to the HKLM hive). See [Registry Entries for Application-Level Add-Ins](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386106(v=vs.110).aspx) for more information.

P.S. Try to run Outlook with admin privileges and see the difference.

Comment: Yes. When I run using admin privileges, it works fine.
When using Outlook 2013, running as admin is not necessary. But only with Outlook 2010, the issue persists.

Comment: Use the HKCU hive for registering the add-in if you want to disable the add-in manually.

Comment: But I want the add in to be installed for all the users. And each user can individually disable the add in. In my case, with outlook 2010, the entries from HKLM are getting copied to HKCU hive everytime I restart outlook.